# Else if statement not working using GET parameters

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to get information out of my database by using GET parameters. The problem is that whenever `$_GET['archived']` is set to `yes` it still executes the `no` / `!isSet` section.

```
if(isSet($_GET['archived']) == "no" || !isSet($_GET['archived'])){
        // find out how many rows are in the table 
        $r = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT  *
            FROM    categories
            WHERE   archived='no'
        ");
    } else if(isSet($_GET['archived']) == "yes"){
        // find out how many rows are in the table 
        $r = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT  *
            FROM    categories
            WHERE   archived='yes'
        ");
    }
```

Comment: Where do you learn that `isset()` will return `no` or `yes` ? Check your code again. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: It does work if the $_GET is set to "no" but not if it is set to "yes".

Comment: **isset** returns **true** or **false**

Comment: OMG, check it again. Dont explain a wrong argue!! And by logic, isset() will always return `false` or `true`, and if used WRONG it will be `false` most of the time.

Comment: just remove the isset. First of all check if the archieved exists. if not, kill the process by returning false. then check the archieved value is either yes or no and then act accordingly

Comment: Please read this http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php and compare it too your issue here. Tip test: `if(true=="foobar"){ echo 'TRUE'; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset` operator returns `true` or `false`. So you have to modify your code like this:

```
if ((isset($_GET['archived']) && $_GET['archived'] == "no") || !isset($_GET['archived'])) {
    // find out how many rows are in the table
    $r = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT  *
            FROM    categories
            WHERE   archived='no'
        ");
} else {
    if (isset($_GET['archived']) && $_GET['archived'] == "yes") {
        // find out how many rows are in the table
        $r = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT  *
            FROM    categories
            WHERE   archived='yes'
        ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple, but works :)

```
    if (!isset($_GET['archived'] || $_GET['archived'] == 'no')){
        // find out how many rows are in the table 
        $r = $connection->prepare("
           SELECT  *
           FROM    categories
           WHERE   archived='no'
       ");
    }
    if ($_GET['archived'] == 'yes') {
        $r = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT  *
            FROM    categories
            WHERE   archived='no'
       ");
    }
```

Also, if you use some framework, do not take GET/POST right from 'magic' variables.

Comment: Look at first line of code in the question. There is a condition for **! isset**

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing the *result* of the isset() function to the strings "no" and "yes". However, isset will return a *boolean value*.

Removing isset() will result in the following code chunk:

```
if($_GET['archived'] == "no") {
    // find out how many rows are in the table 
    $r = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    categories
        WHERE   archived='no'
    ");
} else if($_GET['archived'] == "yes") {
    // find out how many rows are in the table 
    $r = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    categories
        WHERE   archived='yes'
    ");
}
```

Please note that you should always do some pre-processing on the values received from an (untrusted) client, such as $_GET and $_POST, to mitigate the risk of injection.

Background: isset() will only help you to determine whether or not a value has been set. This type of language function is commonly required in non-statically typed programming languages.

Since you are comparing the result of the isset() function to a string, you are asking PHP to compare a boolean value to the string.

From the [official PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL
```

**TL;DR:** Isset is mostly useful for checking if a value was set. Don't use it to compare to an actual value you expect.

Comment: Your example does not determine when $_GET['archived'] does not exists. So when error_reporting set in E_ALL you will see 'undefined variable'